# How do I tell notmuch to scan folders for new messages?

Tags: maildir, notmuch

I'm using `mutt-kz`, `offlineimap` and `notmuch` to read and search my email. I'm syncing between two computers so I need to store things in folders so that some structure is preserved, but I've discovered that when my folders aren't getting indexed. Specifically, I read a message from "Angela" at work and save it to a folder. And then later, at home, I search for "Angela" and I do not see the message I'm looking for. The one I *know* I read yesterday on my office computer. I look in the folder I saved it to and it is there.

So it seems like what is happening is that previously read messages (so no bearing the "New" flag) are are not being indexed by Notmuch if they aren't in the inbox.

Is this expected behavior? How do I tell `notmuch` to index all the mail that `offlineimap` just downloaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only two commands to add emails to the `notmuch` index: `notmuch new` and `notmuch insert`. The former scans the filesystem for any mail that is not yet known to the index. Therefore it is the command you want to look at. (`notmuch insert` is a [MDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_delivery_agent) which also adds the message to the index.)

You could try to execute `notmuch new` from a `offlineimap` hook. Sorry I have not used `offlineimap` so you have to wait for others to answer this part.

Comment: For some reason I had commented out `postsynchook = notmuch new`  and not replaced it with anything else. Totally irrational so it never occurred to me to make sure I was running `notmuch new` -- I assumed my problem was more complex than it actually was.